# Finding and Grouping associations in Python

Tags: python, pandas, model-associations

```
import pandas as pd

# Define the data as a DataFrame with column headers
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Plant": ["A299", "A299", "A299", "A299", "T299", "T299", "T299", "T299", "M199", "M199", "M199", "M199", "A299", "A299", "T299", "A499", "A499", "A499", "A499", "A499", "A299", "A299"],
    "Material": ["M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M3", "M6", "M6", "M8", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "M9", "M9"],
    "Region": ["R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R2", "R4", "R5", "R7", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R9", "R9", "R4"]
})

# Create a dictionary to store materials and their associated regions
material_regions = {}
for _, row in data.iterrows():
    material = row["Material"]
    region = row["Region"]
    if material in material_regions:
        material_regions[material].add(region)
    else:
        material_regions[material] = {region}

# Create a dictionary to store the groups
groups = {}
group_id = 1

# Function to check if two sets have a common element
def has_common_element(set1, set2):
    return bool(set1.intersection(set2))

# Iterate through the materials and create groups based on common regions
for material1, regions1 in material_regions.items():
    assigned = False
    for group, materials in groups.items():
        for material2 in materials:
            regions2 = material_regions[material2]
            if has_common_element(regions1, regions2):
                groups[group].add(material1)
                assigned = True
                break
        if assigned:
            break
    if not assigned:
        groups[group_id] = {material1}
        group_id += 1

# Combine groups that share common materials
final_groups = {}
for group, materials in groups.items():
    new_group = set(materials)
    for other_group, other_materials in groups.items():
        if group != other_group and has_common_element(new_group, other_materials):
            new_group.update(other_materials)
    final_groups[group] = new_group

# Map materials to their final group
material_to_group = {}
for group, materials in final_groups.items():
    for material in materials:
        material_to_group[material] = group

# Create a mapping of regions to groups
region_to_group = {}
for group, materials in final_groups.items():
    regions = set()
    for material in materials:
        regions.update(material_regions[material])
    for region in regions:
        region_to_group[region] = group

# Print the materials and their corresponding groups
for material, group in material_to_group.items():
    print(f"{material} is in Group {group}")

# Print the regions and their corresponding groups
for region, group in region_to_group.items():
    print(f"Region {region} is in Group {group}")
```

From the above, it seems like I cannot tag C2 under group 1, C2 is being used in Region 9, other Material that goes into Region 9 is M9. But M9 is already in Group1 because of Region4. I know it might be tricky, but is it possible to modify the code to tag C2 in Group 1 as well because of its association with M9. please advise

This would be desired output- Group is the output field that i expect
[image]

Updated code after using Networkx package(connected components approach) as advised by @mozway

```
import networkx as nx

# Define the table data
data = [
    ("A299", "M1", "R1"),
    ("A299", "M1", "R2"),
    ("A299", "M1", "R3"),
    ("A299", "M1", "R4"),
    ("T299", "M1", "R1"),
    ("T299", "M1", "R2"),
    ("T299", "M1", "R3"),
    ("T299", "M1", "R4"),
    ("M199", "M1", "R1"),
    ("M199", "M2", "R2"),
    ("M199", "M2", "R2"),
    ("M199", "M3", "R2"),
    ("A299", "M6", "R4"),
    ("A299", "M6", "R5"),
    ("T299", "M8", "R7"),
    ("A499", "C1", "R1"),
    ("A499", "C1", "R2"),
    ("A499", "C1", "R3"),
    ("A499", "C1", "R4"),
    ("A499", "C2", "R9"),
    ("A299", "M9", "R9"),
    ("A299", "M9", "R4"),
]

# Create a graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add nodes (materials and regions) to the graph
for _, material, region in data:
    G.add_node(material, type="material")
    G.add_node(region, type="region")
    G.add_edge(material, region)

# Find connected components
components = list(nx.connected_components(G))

# Create a mapping of materials to their connected component (group)
material_to_group = {}
for idx, component in enumerate(components):
    for node in component:
        if G.nodes[node]["type"] == "material":
            material_to_group[node] = idx + 1

# Print the materials and their corresponding groups
for material, group in sorted(material_to_group.items()):
    print(f"{material} is in Group {group}")
```

Comment: what is your desired output? If we have to read all of your long and inefficient code and figure out your desired output, it will be difficult to answer.

Comment: i have added my Desired output, Group is the Output column that i expect based on associations between Materials and Regions. Note that C2 having an indirect association to group 1 through M9 but that should also be in Group 1

Comment: Can you better explain the logic? Just providing the desired output is not enough. For instance what would it take for T299/M8/R7 to be in Group1?

Comment: Looks like you want the [connected components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlkG1.png), then [see duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72353110/how-to-group-by-one-column-or-another-in-pandas).

Comment: M1 is being used in four regions(R1,R2.R3,R4) M2 is being used in one region-R2, M3 is being used in one region- R2, M6 is being used in two regions(R4,R5), M9 is being used in two regions- R9 and R4,  C1 is being used in four regions(R1,R2.R3,R4), C2 is being used in one region- R9. So as you could see all of these Materials(M1,M2,M3,M6,M9,C1,C2) should be in one group because all these Materials have associated regions. M1,M2.M3,C1 has common region- R2 and M6,M9,M1,C1, has common region R4 and C2,M9 has common region R9. So M1,M2,M3,C1,M6,M9,C1,C2 should be in one group.

Comment: @ArvindMenon can you test if the linked approach is working for you? I considered you only need two columns, if this is not the case (e.g. if you also want to include "Plant", which would give a different result), then please clarify

Comment: the linked approach worked fine. I dont have to include Plant column. I have updated my code that works on my post above. But still there is one problem, if both Material and Region has same value then that value is excluded on the output. not sure if that can be handled by graph theory.